# How to replace specific characters in a string in Clojure?

Tags: string, clojure

I'm trying to replace all single quotation marks with double quotation marks in Clojure. i.e. if the string id " 'name' " I want it to become " "name" ". How can I do that?

I've been trying to use the replace function like this:

```
(clojure.string/replace " 'The color is red' " #"'" """)
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to escape the double quotation mark

```
(clojure.string/replace " 'The color is red' " #"'" "\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this so often I made some convenience functions:

- [quotes->double](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.string#quotes-%3Edouble)
- [quotes->single](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.string#quotes-%3Esingle)

You can find [the details here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  You may also find [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) useful, esp. the documentation list at the end.